# Retention time of older messages in a Kafka topic after changing the configuration

Tags: apache-kafka

I pushed some messages in a kafka-topic. I changed the retention time after that to a much longer time with  :

```
kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --topic $topic--config retention.ms=120960000000
```

Will this apply to only the newer messages pushed in or also to the older ones already in topic before?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`retention.ms` is a topic-level configuration which will affect the data that is currently present in your topic. It doesn't matter if the data has been added to the topic before or after changing this configuration.